# udemy affiliate api Authenticatuion Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, android, api

I am building an android app that uses udemy affiliate api. this is my code

```
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/");
            //open a URL coonnection

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", ***");
```

when connecting to the api, I get a code 403 forbidden error.
I suspect that udemy might be blocking requsts from mobile apps or certain user agents.
id there a way to solve this?

Comment: You may try to send same request via Postman, then you will know for sure, whether it's specific agent that is blocked, or something else.

Comment: thank you Myroslav.

Comment: that did solve my problem.

Comment: in the end, the user agent was indeed blocked, so I changed it, and it worked. I also found another useful tool. so you were very helpful